# laravel and digitalocean install lamp

Tags: apache, laravel, lamp, digital-ocean

hey guys im trying to install laravel 5.1 on my digitalocean droplet and I've done the following steps

1.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

2. enable the Apache mod_rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

3 - to know your mysql password

```
cat /etc/motd.tail
```

4 - to change your password

```
mysqladmin -u root -p'password' password newpassword
```

5 - install Composer, run these commands:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

6 - if you're using Git you can install it very easily:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

7 - now go to /var/www to install first app

```
cd /var/www
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

if got a error when run above command Error like this: The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured you can use for example, to enable the swap

```
cd~
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

8 - Apache vHost PHP Files

Check Apache virtual hosts that come out of the box. Available ones are in sites-available while enabled ones are symlinked from sites-available to sites-enabled.

We'll create new virtual host at /etc/apache2/sites-available/my_app.conf:

```
sudo nano ../etc/apache2/sites-available/my_app.conf
```

and paste

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-site.com
    ServerAlias Xxx.ZxZ.1X7.XxX #your server ip

    DocumentRoot /var/www/your-project-name/public
    <Directory /var/www/your-project-name/public>
        # Don't show directory index
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

        # Allow .htaccess files
        AllowOverride All

        # Allow web access to this directory
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Error and access logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now Enable the Virtual Host using Apache's tool that comes with the Ubuntu package of Apache2:

```
# Symlink it to sites-enabled directory
sudo a2ensite my_app

# Reload Apache so the new configuration is loaded
sudo service apache2 reload
```

all of this info was copied from here 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/install-laravel-on-digitalocean-by-lamp

after all of these steps my domain still points to

```
var/www/html/index.php
```

which is the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. I even tried configuring the apache file to my work environment and it still points to that directory. Any ideas? thanks!

UPDATED VHOST FILE which is still not working

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-site.com
    ServerAlias 159.203.224.150 #your server ip

    DocumentRoot /var/www/collabbro/public
    <Directory /var/www/collabbro/public>
        # Don't show directory index
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

        # Allow .htaccess files
        AllowOverride All

        # Allow web access to this directory
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Error and access logs
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**
this time i followed this tutorial here

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

now I am getting a **500 Server Error**

Comment: What are your permissions on the desired root directory for apache?

Comment: Quick question; did you disable the default site? `a2dissite default` (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: @ChrisForrence im not sure what youre talking about. Very new to setting up everything from the ground up. Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: Sure, @helloworld. When you run `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, what is the output?

Comment: @ChrisForrence i get the following files `000-default.conf `and `my_app.conf`

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski well im root user so does that matter?

Comment: @helloworld that's not exactly what I'm asking, I'm asking if there are world readable permissions on the directory and it's content.  You might also have the default site enabled it sounds like.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski would you know the steps on solving this?

Comment: @helloworld not without this info.  For the default site, use a2ensite to enable your sight and disable the default.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski i followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts and now im getting a 500 error

Comment: Ok, so a 500 error would probably mean you have an issue with your apache conf file.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski ill update my question and post it. hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

i fixed the solution with these following links

Configuring my apache

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

and then properly deploying laravel 5.1

https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.fasm9hfx5

hope this helps people in the future